# Rspec `allow` not preventing method evaluation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

**RESOLVED**

Ran into an issue where `allow` is not stubbing a class method. I know this because if I stick a `pry` in the inner_method below, rspec will halt @ it during evaluation of the test. This behavior ONLY happens when the returned value is a `factory_girl` factory

example:

```
context '.wrapping_method returns inner value' do
   it 'returns a value' do
     allow(Thing).to receive(:method).and_return 'what'
     expect(Thing.wrapping_method).to eql 'what'
   end
end
```

`Thing` class structure could be considered:

```
class Thing do
   def self.wrapping_method
      inner_method || = 'nothing from inner'
   end

   def self.inner_method
       # do some sort of thing here and return a value
       binding.pry # <= eval reaches this
   end
end
```

It should be noted that other apps I have do not perform like this, and i am stumped as to what is different here.

**RESOLUTION** code performed above the `wrapping_method` caused a exception which was handled strangely, and somehow the test context was lost, but the `wrapper_method` soldiered on and `inner_method` was triggered. *Resolved by fixing the strange exception handling*

Comment: Safe to assume the mismatch between `:method` and `inner_method` is just a typo?

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom yes sir. I actually figured it out. The issue was caused by code about the `wrapper_method` call causing an error that was not being handled appropriately - some sort of odd exception handling broke the test out of the context and `allowed` was ignored but the method continued processing. Weird stuff. Thanks for the time with eyes on this

Comment: I'll hold my close vote (this is in the close review queue), but can you phrase this into a proper Q&A?